# Get Latest using TFS API

Tags: .net, tfs, alm, tfs-sdk

I am trying to use the TFS API to retrieve the latest code from the server within a workspace.
I found this question:

[How do you get the latest version of source code using the Team Foundation Server SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827651/how-do-you-get-the-latest-version-of-source-code-using-the-team-foundation-serve)

Which is essentially what I want to do; however, I want to use an existing workspace, and only retrieve a certain section of the code.  Is this possible?

For example (using the example given in the above question):

```
workspace.Get(request, GetOptions.GetAll | GetOptions.Overwrite, "$/MyFolder/MyProject");
```

Is something like this possible without setting up a new workspace or something?

Comment: Please do not use GetAll and Overwrite unless you really need to - they add quite a bit of unnecessary processing overhead to the server and client, as well as network overhead.

Comment: I absolutely do need to, because the point of the program is to retrieve all the latest source code (within the specified sub-directory) to the client PC.  It should be an infrequent process though.

Comment: Right, my point is that the server is smart enough to give you the latest source code without force or overwrite flags, unless you've done something horrible to your workspace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to gain access to your workspace with something like this:

```
var vcServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
Workspace myWorkspace = vcServer.GetWorkspace("workspaceName", "workspaceOwner");
```

Then you get latest with a

```
 myWorkspace.Get();
```

or refine what you want get by consulting [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.get%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

In order to find out about your workspace(s) details navigate in VS to

> "File" > "Source Control" > "Workspaces..."